# Working with nested maps using Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

My current approach exploiting Streams API in conjunction with forEach loop:

```
public Map<String, Client> clientsWithMostPurchasesInEachCategory(Map<Client, Map<Product,Integer>> shopping) {

    Map<String, Client> result = new HashMap<>();

    Map<Client, Map<String, BigDecimal>> temp =
            shopping.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                             Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream(),
                             Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getCategory(),
                             Collectors.mapping(ee -> ee.getKey().getPrice().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(ee.getValue())),
                             Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))))));

    /*curious, how could I refactor that piece of code, so the method uses only one stream chain? */
    temp.forEach((client, value) 
        -> value.forEach((category, value1) 
        -> {
               if (!result.containsKey(category) ||
                   temp.get(result.get(category)).get(category).compareTo(value1) < 0)
                   result.put(category, client);
           }));    

    return result;

}
```

As the method's name sugggests, I want to find a map `Map <String, Client>`, containing Client with most purchases (as value) in specified category (as key) in each product's category

**shopping** is basically a map: `Map<Client, Map<Product,Integer>>`,

- The outer Key represents the Client
- The inner Key represents the Product. Product class members are **name, category, price (BigDecimal)**
- the inner maps value (Integer) reprents the number of specified product which belong to a specific client

---

Not sure, if that's even possible? `Collectors.collectingAndThen` maybe could be useful?

Comment: (opinion) to do it in a single stream, the first `groupingBy` operation should be based upon the category and not client, then not sure what has led to such a poor choice of data structure to represent `shopping` as a whole and even in terms of `Map` what is the essence of `Product` is all you're bothered about is the `category` here. Seems like the problem has been overly complicated. Would suggest, stating down the primary inputs that you have and your requirements to approach the problem in a much simpler way.

Comment: @nullpointer that shopping data structure was choosen for learning purposes only. I do know, that's not the best choice

Comment: @nullpointer . As regards to `groupingBy` based  on category, you prolly can't flatten the whole map structure to extract product's category and then work on with original shopping map values

Answer (score 1):

You can use StreamEx library, and do smth like this

```
public static Map<String, Client> clientsWithMostPurchasesInEachCategory(Map<Client, Map<Product, Integer>> shopping) {
        return EntryStream.of(shopping)
                .flatMapKeyValue(((client, productQuantityMap) ->
                        EntryStream.of(productQuantityMap)
                                .mapToValue((p, q) -> p.getPrice().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(q)))
                                .mapKeys(Product::getCategory)
                                .map(e -> new ClientCategorySpend(client, e.getKey(), e.getValue())))
                )
                .groupingBy(
                        ClientCategorySpend::getCategory,
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(ClientCategorySpend::getSpend)),
                                t -> t.get().getClient())
                );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty much doomed the moment you grouped by client. The
top level `Collectors.groupingBy` must use the category as the grouping by key.

To do that you would `flatMap` before collecting, so you get a flat stream of
client + category + spend elements.

Here's one way to do it. I'll first define a POJO for the elements of the flattened stream:

```
  static class ClientCategorySpend
  {
      private final Client client;
      private final String category;
      private final BigDecimal spend;

      public ClientCategorySpend(Client client, String category, BigDecimal spend)
      {
          this.client = client;
          this.category = category;
          this.spend = spend;
      }

      public String getCategory()
      {
          return category;
      }

      public Client getClient()
      {
          return client;
      }

      public BigDecimal getSpend()
      {
          return spend;
      }
  }
```

And now the function:

```
public static Map<String, Client> clientsWithMostPurchasesInEachCategory(Map<Client, Map<Product, Integer>> shopping)
{
     // <1>
     Collector<? super ClientCategorySpend, ?, BigDecimal> sumOfSpendByClient = Collectors.mapping(ClientCategorySpend::getSpend,
             Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add));


     // <2>
     Collector<? super ClientCategorySpend, ?, Map<Client, BigDecimal>> clientSpendByCategory = Collectors.groupingBy(
             ClientCategorySpend::getClient,
             sumOfSpendByClient
     );

     // <3>
     Collector<? super ClientCategorySpend, ?, Client> maxSpendingClientByCategory = Collectors.collectingAndThen(
             clientSpendByCategory,
             map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                     .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
                     .map(Map.Entry::getKey).get()
     );

     return shopping.entrySet().stream()
            // <4>
             .flatMap(
                     entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet().stream().map(
                             entry2 -> new ClientCategorySpend(entry.getKey(),
                                     entry2.getKey().category,
                                     entry2.getKey().price.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(entry2.getValue())))
                     )
             ).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ClientCategorySpend::getCategory, maxSpendingClientByCategory));
}
```

Once I have a stream of `ClientCategorySpend` (4), I group it by category. I use
the `clientSpendByCategory` collector (2) to create a map between the client and the total spend in the category. This in turn depends on sumToSpendByClient (1) which is basically a reducer that sums up the spends. You then get to use `collectingAndThen` as you suggested,
reducing each `Map<Client, BigDecimal>` to a single client using `max`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do ;)

```
public Map<String, Client> clientsWithMostPurchasesInEachCategory(Map<Client, Map<Product, Integer>> shopping) {

    return shopping
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> Pair.of(
                    entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue()
                            .entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .map(e -> Pair.of(
                                    e.getKey().getCategory(),
                                    e.getKey().getPrice().multiply(
                                            BigDecimal.valueOf(e.getValue()))))
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                    Pair::getKey,
                                    Pair::getValue,
                                    BigDecimal::add))))

            // Here we have: Stream<Pair<Client, Map<String, BigDecimal>>>
            // e.g.: per each Client we have a map { category -> purchase value }

            .flatMap(item -> item.getValue()
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(e -> Pair.of(
                            e.getKey(), Pair.of(item.getKey(), e.getValue()))))

            // Here: Stream<Pair<String, Pair<Client, BigDecimal>>>
            // e.g.: entries stream { category, { client, purchase value } }
            // where there are category duplicates, so we must select those  
            // with highest purchase value for each category.

            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Pair::getKey,
                    Pair::getValue,
                    (o1, o2) -> o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue()) > 0 ?
                            o2 : o1))

            // Now we have: Map<String, Pair<Client, BigDecimal>>,
            // e.g.: { category -> { client, purchase value } }
            // so just get rid of unnecessary purchase value...

            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue().getKey()));

}
```

`Pair` is `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`. If you do not want to use Appache Commons library you may use `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` instead.